# Set or change the color of highlighted text using JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery AutoComplete on a ASP.net page.  When I type in the textbox, it returns a list, but when I use a down arrow key to go down, the item is selected without being highlighted (The selected text is displayed on th textbox, but no color).

Where can I set/change the color of selected item in the list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming#http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming

for theming jquery-ui.

generally all you need is to attch your styles to the right class.
i think it is ui-state-hover and ui-active-menuitem it your case.